# Sending email with Classic ASP through Godaddy

Tags: email, asp-classic, godaddy-api

I'm trying to send email using Classic ASP from my website at Godaddy. Unfortunately, the cod I have from 10-15 years ago doesn't work (imagine that! lol). Here's the code. Can someone tell me what has changed since then? desperately await your reply. Thank you!

```
    Set cdoConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration") 
    With cdoConfig.Fields
      .Item(cdoSMTPConnectionTimeout) = 10
      .Item(cdoSMTPAuthenticate) = false
      .Item(cdoSendUserName) = "email@mywebsite.com"
      .Item(cdoSendPassword) = "MyPassword"
      .Item(cdoURLProxyServer) = "server:25"
     '.Item(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPickup
      .Item(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort
      .Item(cdoSMTPServer) = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net"
      .Item(cdoURLGetLatestVersion) = True
      .Update
    End With

'Create mail object
Set cdoMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

'Apply the settings to the message object then send the email
With cdoMessage
    Set .Configuration = cdoConfig
    .From = "Support (email@mywebsite)"
    .To = "The User (user@email.com)"
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "This is a test email."
    .TextBody = "This is a test email. If it were a real email there would be some blah blah blah here! This concludes the test of the Godaddy email message."
    .Send
End With

'Cleanup mail objects
Set cdoMessage = Nothing
Set cdoConfig = Nothing
```

Comment: CDO just works *(regardless of how old it is)* the issue will be the email provider details have changed in some way, double-check the provider information is correct before pointing the finger at CDO.

Comment: I figured it out. Answer below. Can I have my points back now? Please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok folks. This is for the people that need a guiding hand from time to time. However, make sure you enter the right username and password. When hosting on Godaddy you could have up to three different usernames and passwords. You have your Godaddy account username and password (that's not it!), you have a username and password for Plesk (that's not it either!). Then you have a username and password for your primary website (that's the one you want!). Even though you might have several different websites under your hosting, only one will be the primary. Mine was for the email and password that are associated with that prime website. Once you get this code posted you should be good to go. However, you might have to wait a while in order for it to start working. For me it took about 8 hours for the DNS to catch hold of what I was doing and start sending my emails through. Once it did though, now it works great! Enjoy!

```
    Dim objNewMail

    'Your email information
    Set objNewMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    objNewMail.From = "your-email@this-website.com"
    objNewMail.Cc = "your-email@this-website.com"
    objNewMail.To   = "send-to@their-email.com"
    objNewMail.Subject = "This is a test email"
    objNewMail.TextBody = "this is a test email"

    ' GoDaddy SMTP Settings
    objNewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=2
    objNewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")="relay-hosting.secureserver.net"
    objNewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")=25 
    objNewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
    objNewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/cdoSendUserName") = "your-primary-website-username"
    objNewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/cdoSendPassword") = "your-primary-website-password"
    objNewMail.Configuration.Fields.Update
    objNewMail.Send

    'After the Send method, NewMail Object become Invalid
    Set objNewMail = Nothing
```

Comment: This worked for me, I just ended up removing the authentication fields for the username and password.